# get the parmeter from ajax to node.js to mongoDB

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, mongodb

i have this problem when i try to do some test by clicking a button which call a JavaScript function that does an ajax call and pass a parameter to my node.js server(express) which save it to my mongoDB.

the problem is that all the time i see the value in the DB as null, after researching i found that the problem is how to get the parameter `"name"` and read it on the node.js side

i try `req.body.name` or `req.query.name` but stil nothing..

hope you can help me,
maybe its in my code or syntax problem, wait for your help

java script code :

```
function savePre()
{
    var parameters = { name: 'test' };

    $.ajax({
        url: '/savePre',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(parameters),
        success: function () {},
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}
```

node.js code (in the `index.js` code) :

```
exports.savePre = function(db) {
    return function(req, res) {

        // Get our form values. These rely on the "name" attributes
        var json = req.query.name;

        // Set our collection
        var collection = db.get('PresentationCollection');

        // Submit to the DB
        collection.insert({
            "JsonToSave": json
        }, function (err, doc) {
            if (err) {
                // If it failed, return error
                res.send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
            }
       });

    }
}
```

Comment: what's the server side application framework? you need [bodyParser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) if using express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your client side code can be improved without `JSON.stringify`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/savePre',
    type: 'POST',
    data: parameters,
    success: function () {}
});
```